# Provide additional DLL Directory in node-module using bindings.gyp

Tags: windows, dll, node-gyp, node-addon-api

We have an app with multiple node-module having dependency on the same DLL (C.DLL). Both of these node-modules needs the C.DLL to be present in their directory for successful loading. Our current structure looks like this-

```
<node-module>
    <node-a>
         <build/Release/A.node>
         <C.DLL>
    <node-b>
         <build/Release/B.node>
         <C.DLL>
```

We want to use the C.DLL present in `node-a` while loading the `node-b` to avoid additional coppies of the same DLL. One way that works for us is by adding the path to `<node-a/C.DLL>` to system `PATH` var. Also creating a symlink of C.DLL inside `node-b` folder also works. Is there any way to do this using VCLinkerTools or bindings.gyp?